# JustGage custom sectors high to low

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael, justgage

I'm currently using [JustGage](http://justgage.com/) and think it's great.  However I wish to have a scale that goes from high to low i.e. 100 - 0 rather than all the demo'd code which is low to high.

Is this possible?  I have tried to read the documentation but can't seem to find anything for this.

Comment: I think you can do, can you provide some of your effort in www.jsfiddle.net please

Comment: @bboymaanu  I ended up not worrying about it as for now it became low priority.  However I had a quick look and couldn't figure it out